# How to increase storage capacity of already deployed cluster in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed airflow via docker on kubernetes cluster and now I need to increase the persistent volume's storage capacity. While editing the yaml file via UI, I get this error:

```
PersistentVolumeClaim "data-pallet-airflow-worker-0" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: field is immutable after creation
```

Comment: Volume resizing is supported as beta feature since [Kubernetes 1.11](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/). Are you perhaps using an earlier version or maybe using a volume class that does not support volume expansion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing size of persistent disks on kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594836/increasing-size-of-persistent-disks-on-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @aerokite, this question seems to have already been answered in this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594836/increasing-size-of-persistent-disks-on-kubernetes?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

> Posted as a community wiki.